# Using cylindrical coordinates evaluate $ \ \iiint_E \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dv$

Tags: multiple-integral

Using cylindrical coordinates evaluate $\iiint_E \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\, dv$, where $E$ is the region inside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=9$ and between   the planes $z=1$ and $z=5$. $

Let $ x=r \cos \theta,  \ y=r \sin \theta$  and $z=z$. Then the integral becomes $\int_{z=1}^{z=5} \int_{r=-3}^{r=3} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2 \pi} r \cdot r \, dr \, d \theta \, dz.$  Is it true setting, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The integral in the OP is not quite correct;  the lower limit on $r$ is "$0$," not "$-3$" since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge 0$.

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\iiint_E \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\,dv&=\int_1^5 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3 r\,dr\,R\,d\phi\,dz\\\\
&=8\pi \int_0^3r^2\,dr\\\\
&=72 \pi
\end{align}$$